# Can iOS updates be forced OTA without DEP?

Tags: ios, version, mdm, ota, apple-profile-manager

I have a "Kiosk" type app for iPads that I'd like to sell to 3rd parties. The App runs in Single App Mode.
What I also want to offer is over-the-air control of:

- App Updates
- iOS Updates

without any user intervention.

I can setup the iPad as Supervised using Apple Configurator and then it does look like I can upgrade the App using an MDM - can anyone confirm they have done this? Which MDM did you use?

Also is it possible to force an iOS update? Reports mostly say Apple’s Device Enrolment Program is needed which would mean the 3rd parties have to purchase iPads through DEP?

Also can all this be done without an MDM but using Apple’s Profile Manager and OS X Server instead?

Interested in anyones experience in this area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MDM can be used to update an app. The OS updates can only be forced through DEP. But in the case of a kiosk app, you cannot update the app over the air. The only way is to

- remove the app from kiosk mode.
- Enable kiosk for some other app.
- Update the required app.
- And then put the app back in kiosk mode.

All these steps can be done over the air using an MDM. I have tried out Hexnode MDM. The enabling and disabling of kiosk mode is so simple and fast. Its worth checking out.